# Can I begin installing laminate flooring in a hallway?

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor

I am a new home buyer and I want to replace some carpeted areas with laminate. Especially where my dogs are already chewing at it. I can't afford to get all of the material at once. My question is since the area that is the worse is the hallway can I begin there and what is the recommended direction to go?

Answer (score 1):

You sure can. In fact, it's often best practice to start in a hallway, which is one of the places where a crooked installation really shows against the walls By starting there you minimize the chance of visual oddity.

Typically, wood flooring is installed parallel to the longer side of the room. In the case of a hallway, you'd run it lengthwise.

Comment: If my boards are running parallel to the hallway than usually the hall is where I would finish an install.  Also I wouldn't recommend someone pick the direction of their flooring without seeing a full floor plan.

Comment: I gave a reason for starting with a hallway. Please provide your reason for finishing there (ideally in an answer). I'll be happy to upvote alternative viewpoints.

Comment: I am not saying I would or wouldn't.  For instance if there was a tile room 12 feet from hallway that the boards would butt up to the choice of direction would be dependent on the type of transition wanted.  Also manufacturers have constraints on install methods in larger rooms.  Just not enough info to give someone any sort of recommendation in a case like this.